# What is the label file for tensor flow on android

Tags: tensorflow, label, tensorflow-lite

I am learning the implementation of the TensorFlow model at android.
In this tutorial, it put the  labels.txt and model.tflite files into assets folder .
https://blog.notyouraveragedev.in/android/image-classification-in-android-using-tensor-flow/
What is that labels.txt should be?
I have a file that has the following format :

```
"1": "1 Cent,Australian dollar,australia",
"2": "2 Cents,Australian dollar,australia",
"3": "5 Cents,Australian dollar,australia",
"4": "10 Cents,Australian dollar,australia",
"5": "20 Cents,Australian dollar,australia",
"6": "50 Cents,Australian dollar,australia",
"7": "1 Dollar,Australian dollar,australia",
"8": "2 Dollars,Australian dollar,Australia",
```

Is it that labels.txt file or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the answer now.
It should be a pure class name.
eg. 1 Cent,Australian dollar,Australia